# How to vectorize a sum of dot products between a normal and array of points

Tags: matlab, vector, matrix, vectorization, dot-product

I need to evaluate following expression (in pseudo-math notation):

> `∑ipi⋅n`

where `p` is a matrix of three-element vectors and `n` is a three-element vector. I can do this with for loops as follows but I can't figure out
how to vectorize this:

```
p = [1 1 1; 2 2 2];
n = [3 3 3];
s = 0;
for i = 1:size(p, 1)
    s = s + dot(p(i, :), n)
end
```

Comment: matlab has `+=` operator? what version are you using?

Comment: @Shai Obviously this sample code hasn't been tested. The for loop has also been carelessly written. I've fixed them both.

Comment: @EitanT I am working on an old matlab version, I was kind of hoping they implemented `+=` ... too bad.

Comment: @etan actually that was tested, I just happend to have m==p on my environment and I mislead by stating Matlab as this was actually on Octave, sorry I assumed they were compatible as far as += is concerned

Comment: @nyholku Sorry, I take my accusation back then...  :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why complicate things? How about simple matrix multiplication:

```
s = sum(p * n(:))
```

where `p` is assumed to be an *M*-by-3 matrix.

Comment: This answer will grant you matlab gold badge! congrats!

Comment: Thanks Eitan, looks like just what I was looking for, now I just need to check if this is expands to the real use case which is a bit more complicated

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it with `bsxfun`:

```
sum(sum(bsxfun(@times,p,n)))
```

Comment: `bsxfun` is a lot of fun, but in this specific solution it is not in place :(... no +1 for this `bsxfun`.

Comment: @Shai You've mentioned `bsxfun` so many times, that whenever you mention it now you're talking in rhymes! ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
----------


% Is it the same for this case?


----------


n = 200;                  % depending on the computer it might be

m = 1000*n;               % that n needs to be chosen differently

A = randn(n,m);

x = randn(n,1);

p = zeros(m,1);

q = zeros(1,m);
tic;

for i = 1:m

    p(i) = sum(x.*A(:,i));
    q(i) = sum(x.*A(:,i));
end
time = toc; disp(['time = ',num2str(time)]);
```

Comment: Find (as well) a solution in which it is not necessary to transpose A. Of
course, present the commands that you have used for vectorization.